# Public folder for my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, directory, public

I want use public folder in the server for my app, like dropbox, but I have one problem with dropbox, it requires auth for user. I need that application has access to public folder with some app key or something else, but not auth from user.
I mean, one man updates this folder and all applications downloads the update from it without auth from user.
It should supports ios.

Comment: Is it me are does this read like there are security issues in the way you want to have this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You surely need to have web-service layer(API) for this kind of requirements.

The most simplest and effective solution as for me(if you have no backend developers in your team or don't want to develop server-side software for your purposes), is to use external BAAS tool(Backend as a service).

You can check Parse, for example, http://www.parse.com
There are a lot of other services, but this one is really great in my opinion.
They have really good documentation and easily understandable SDK for iOS.

It allows you to store information, retrieve it, without or with authorization (you decide how).

Comment: what about auto synchronization foolder from server and folder in devices(like dropbox)?

Comment: It's your app's responsibility for synchronization files. You can refresh a list of shared(stored at parse.com) objects at any time. For example, each time your app will become active (and maybe internally by a timer) you reload a list of files stored in a server. For storing files, you can create a list of PFObjects(object abstraction), each of them is linked to a particular PFFile (file abstraction). More details are available at their documentation